# TELNET -l username option is not working

Tags: linux, login, telnet, pam

Telnet man page says username present in -l option is passed to telnet server via ENVIRON variable. If telnet server accepts this ENVIRON, it won't prompt for username.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet

Our unit is running Linux. When we try "telnet -l [username]" to login to the unit, it still prompts for username.

How can we make telnet server to accept ENVIRON variable so it wont prompt for username option. Linux in our unit uses pam and login module for user access.

Answer (score 1):

The correct use would be:

```
$ telnet -l <user_name>
```

instead of only:

```
$ telnet -l
```

Comment: Yes, used the command "telnet -l <username>" but still it prompts for username. I need to know how to fix it.